# Change git diff default -U value

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

I can't seem to figure out how to specify this in my ~/.gitconfig so that anytime I run `git diff <filename>` it will automatically include `-U<line number>` by default so I don't have to enter it each time.

Answer (score 5):

It's called "context lines":

```
git config --global diff.context 5
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffcontext).